# How can I reflect a point with respect to the plane?

Tags: matrix, transformation

How can I reflect a point with respect to a plane?

Example:

I have three points (0,0,2), (4,0,0) and (0,8,0). And I have a point (x,y,z). From these, I want derive a composite transformation matrix. How can I do that?

Comment: What have you tried? What problems did you run into? And lastly:  smells like homework, is it?

Comment: @Eric I donot know how to solve it ?

Comment: @user1796528 welcome. On this site, those kind of questions normally require you to have already some work done. This is because this is not a place to just wait for someone answer any and all of your questions. You have to show work

Comment: From the way your question is worded, it sounds like your first three points identify your plane and the fourth is the one you want to reflect about that plane. Is that correct?

Answer (score 5):

Given the following:

- **A** as the 4x4 [augmented translation matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_transformation#Augmented_matrix) to move any of the point of the plane into the origin
- **I** as the 3x3 [identity matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_matrix)
- **N** as the 3-dimensional [unit normal vector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_vector) for the plane (calculable by creating a cross product from any two non-parallel lines on the plane, then normalising them)

The calculation steps for the augmented reflection matrix are as follows:

1) Calculate the 3x3 reflection matrix **R<sub>0</sub>** for a plane with the same normal vector, but which lies at the origin

**R<sub>o</sub>** = **I** - 2 **NN<sup>T</sup>**

2) Augment the reflection matrix to create the augmented reflection matrix **R<sub>A</sub>**

3) Calculate the final augmented reflection matrix by first applying the translation **A**, mirroring the point by **R<sub>A</sub>**, then applying the reverse of the translation **A<sup>-1</sup>**

**R** = **AR<sub>A</sub>A<sup>-1</sup>**

Comment: A derivation : [Rotation about an arbitrary axis and reflection through an arbitrary plane](http://ami.ektf.hu/uploads/papers/finalpdf/AMI_40_from175to186.pdf) by Emőd Kovács

Answer (score 4):

Three points, **A**, **B** and **C** define a plane. The lines **AB** and **AC** are both on the plane, so their normalised cross product, perpendicular to both lines, is the plane's normal **n**:

**n** = normalise( (**B** - **A**) ⨯ (**C** - **A**) )

The equation for the plane is given by: **n** · **x** + d = 0, where -d is the displacement between the plane and the origin in the normal direction, i.e.: d = -**n** · **A**.

An arbitrary point **x** can be described as the sum of two vectors, **u** pointing from plane to point in the normal direction, **v** being the other component:

**u** = (**x** · **n** + d) **n**

**v** = **x** - **u**

The mirror image of **x** can then be calculated by flipping the **u**-component: **x'** = -**u** + **v**. Now that **x'** is known, capturing the calculation in a transformation matrix is trivial: solve **T x** = **x'** for **T**.

Comment: The question asks for a matrix solution.  Your explanation is solid, just not quite what the asker is looking for. :)

Comment: Good note. The transformation matrix is easily found from here, but that's rather moot if you have calculated **x'** already. There are of course shortcuts and simplifications you could apply, but in my opinion, going into detail there calls for proper mathematical formatting.